# How to get UserCustomData in Kentico CMS

Tags: c#, kentico

I'd like to get some custom data for the currently authenticated user in Kentico CMS.  I've tried the following without success:

```
CMSContext.CurrentUser.UserCustomData["CustomFieldName"];
CMSContext.CurrentUser.UserCustomData.GetValue("CustomFieldName");
```

It looks like UserCustomData property is supposed to be a data container for this info, but I keep getting null references when I try to access it.  How can I access this data without creating a new query or object wrapper for the CMS_User table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will allow you to access any field from the CMS_User table:

```
// instantiate a UserInfo object and populate it with data
// by passing in the user's UserID.  Here I've passed in
// the current user's UserID
UserInfo ui = UserInfoProvider.GetUserInfo(CMSContext.CurrentUser.UserID);

// retrieve data from the db by passing in the field name
var aVariable = ui.GetValue("FieldName");
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is curious. The 'UserCustomData' field is an xml field in the database that can be accessed via the Kentico API as if it were Key-Value container.

You can store information in there temporarily, but I'd recommend against it - it's likely you'll end up needing to do something with the data you put in there later and wishing you'd made it a new field.

The 'CustomData' fields are also available on any other Info Object, but all the same I recommend not using them.

Comment: So "UserCustomData" isn't a wrapper for custom data fields on the CMS_User table?

Comment: Nope - All Kentico data objects are like a wrapper around a .Net DataSet object. When you add a new field into the 'fields' tab in Document/Page types, Custom Tables or System tables it's adding a new column in the SQL Databse, which then shows in that DataSet. The GetValue method and square brackets operator just retrieve the column value based on the name of the SQL column. If you're wanting to experiment you could try storing something in the UserCustomData field, and then use 'ui.GetValue("UserCustomData")' - you'll get back the xml as a string.

Comment: Ah, I see where the UserCustomData field is now.  It's in CMS_UserSettings, not CMS_User.  I get how the mapping works, I just couldn't figure out where that field was coming from.  Now that I'm looking at the metadata for the UserInfo class, there's a whole lot more in there than just what's in CMS_User.